# Vim(Gvim) - How do I install a script on Windows 7?

Tags: vim

I want to install this closetag.vim script:

http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=13

It says

> place this file in your standard vim scripts directory and source it
>   while editing the file you wish to close tags in.

And this is shown as an example:

```
:let g:closetag_html_style=1
:source ~/.vim/scripts/closetag.vim
```

1) What is my standard vim scripts directory on W7?

I have neither `.vim` nor `scripts` folder on my system. And if I have\am expected to create one (or ones) where should it (they) be placed? `%ProgramFiles%\Vim\vim80` or `%ProgramFiles%\Vim\vimfiles` or maybe somewhere else?

1.1) Also, this might be a silly thing to ask about, but why do I keep seeing that tilde in path almost every time I read about Vim. Does it mean that Vim is used primarily by Mac/Linux people? Why is that?

2) What does it mean to source the script? Run a command like this `let g:closetag_html_style=1` in command mode in Vim?

Btw what does `style=1` mean here?

And if I want it to work by default for all `html\xhtml\xml` files, what do I do? Put this command to `_vimrc` file?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find the answers to all your questions just by reading the plugin description carefully. Unfortunately, it is both poorly written *and* factually incorrect.

1. **What is my standard vim scripts directory on W7?**

   On Windows, you are supposed to put custom and third-party scripts in various places under:

   ```
   C:\Users\username\vimfiles\
   ```

   **But that's not what the author means by "standard vim scripts directory".** What he is referring to is this:

   ```
   C:\Users\username\vimfiles\scripts\
   ```

   which is not standard *at all*.

   **Also, this might be a silly thing to ask about, but why do I keep seeing that tilde in path almost every time I read about Vim. Does it mean that Vim is used primarily by Mac/Linux people? Why is that?**

   Yes, Vim is primarily used by UNIX-like systems users. Because of [history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)).
2. **What does it mean to source the script? Run a command like this `let g:closetag_html_style=1` in command mode in Vim?**

   No. Read your question again.
3. **Btw what does `style=1` mean here?**

   Nothing.

   But `:let g:closetag_html_style=1` means "set the `g:closetag_html_style` option to true".
4. **And if I want it to work by default for all html\xhtml\xml files, what do I do? Put this command to `_vimrc` file?**

   No. This is explained on the plugin's page:

   > For greater convenience, load this script in an autocommand:

   ```
   :au Filetype html,xml,xsl source ~/.vim/scripts/closetag.vim
   ```

   Which is wrong on many levels.

---

Here is what you *actually* have to do to use that script:

1. Save the `closetag.vim` script to the following location:

   ```
   C:\Users\username\vimfiles\scripts\closetag.vim
   ```

   Create `vimfiles\` and/or `vimfiles\scripts\` if they don't exist.
2. Add the lines below to `C:\Users\username\_vimrc`:

   ```
   augroup closetag
       autocmd!
       autocmd Filetype html,xhtml,xml,xsl runtime scripts/closetag.vim
   augroup END
   let g:closetag_html_style = 1
   ```

---

Reference:

```
:help startup
:help :source
:help :runtime
:help :let
:help autocommand
```

Comment: That script doesn't seem to work, at least for me. But your answer is excellent, romainl. Thank you very much for your help!